# Makefile run an action before everything

Tags: gnu-make

For building my target I have a list of prerequisites contained in a file `list.txt` and a script for generating this file `generate-list.sh`.

I need the script to be executed as first thing every time I invoke the make in order to have the `list.txt` updated and to give ti `make` the right list of prerequisites.

```
prebuild:
    touch list.txt

.SECONDEXPANSION:
exe: prebuild $$(shell cat list.txt)
    touch exe

<files in list.txt>:
    <rules for generating these files>
```

In this way when I run `make` I first get an error from `cat` saying that `list.txt` does not exist, then `list.txt` is generated but since the `cat` failed the prerequisites contained in `list.txt` are not generated.

Answer (score 4):

One method you could use, given that `generate_list.sh` must be executed at the very start every time, would be to explicitly execute it using the [`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) function. This would mean altering your `makefile` to something like

```
$(shell ./generate_list.sh > /dev/null)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
exe: $(shell cat list.txt)
    touch exe
    @echo $?

<files in list.txt>:
    <rules for generating these files>
```

Executing this `makefile` produces

```
$ make
touch exe
deps.c test.c
```

where my `generate_list.sh` file contains

```
#!/bin/bash

touch test.c deps.c
echo deps.c test.c > list.txt

echo 'Created prerequisites list.'
```

---

#### Notes

1. `/dev/null` is included in `$(shell ./generate_list.sh > /dev/null)` incase your `generate_list.sh` produces an output as this would cause an error in `make` of

   ```
   $ make
   GNUmakefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
   ```

   otherwise.
2. `@echo $?` shows that all of the prerequisites in `list.txt` are now included as prerequisites of `exe`.

---

#### Alternate Method Based on Auto Dependency Generation

What you are attempting to do is very similar to [automatic](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) [dependency](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) generation which can be accomplished using the [`-include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) directive in `make`. For future usage you may want to consider going down this route and altering your `generate_list.sh` script to create a `makefile` that can be included in your main `makefile`.